# Java sorted nested Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a structure Recipe with has array of ingredients.

```
Recipe
 String title
 List<Ingredient> ingredients

Ingredient
 String title
 Date bestBefore
```

I need to generate a list orderd of recipes by oldest ingredient of all recipes.
Example:

```
Recipe1
 Ingredients [a:2020,b:2020,c:2020]
Recipe2
 Ingredients [a:1999,b:2000,c:2001]
Recipe3
 Ingredients [a:2000,b:2000,c:1800]

=> Recipe3,Recipe2,Recipe1
```

This is because Recipe3 has oldest ingredient 1800. The next after is Recipe2 and Recipe1.

Answer (score 1):

```
recipes.sort(Comparator.comparing(
        r -> Collections.min(r.getIngredients,
                        Comparator.comparing(Ingredient::getBestBefore))
                .getBestBefore()));
```

`Collections.min()` finds the ingredient with the earliest *best before* date for each recipe. It will break woth a `NoSuchElementException` if some recipe has an empty list of ingredients.

Code is not compiled and tested.

And no, I am not using any stream. Why should I?